# How can I tag a page in a Facebook photo that isn't among the three pages found by the search?

Tags: facebook, facebook-photos, facebook-tags

If I want to tag a page in a photo (new way of adding a photo to a page's photo album), I type `@` and then the page name, and a dropdown is shown with a list of candidates. What happens is that some times it doesn't show the page I want among the options, only finding pages with, for instance, very few people on it. Or if I want a page for a musician, it shows the wikipedia page, not the official one.

I have the page link, I "like" the page, the page has photos added to it (so it's in theory possible and permitted to do this), but the page still doesn't show on the list.

Comment: What is the page you are trying to tag?

Comment: maybe the page has access restrictions?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook has a FAQ for this:  [I can't tag a Page in a photo.](https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=224824320861789)

> You can only tag certain types of Pages in photos at this time. These include Pages most likely to appear in photos, such as brands, people and products. If a Page is eligible, you don't need to like it in order to tag it in a photo.
>
> If you manage a Page that's eligible to be tagged in photos but you're currently unable to do so, [let the Pages team know](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/398692706840404) so we can try to fix what might be broken.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but found a solution:
You first need to like this page.

If you try to tag a page with your own Facebook page, you will also need to like the page you want to tag with your page account: Click top right on settings + "switch Facebook as" and choose your own Facebook page before to like the page you want to tag in your post.